# Custom query and page-navi not working

Tags: wordpress

i am using custom query and wp-page-navi plugin. But when i click on page 1 2 3 its showing content only of first page. How to solve that issue? On archive page its working and categories.

```
<?php
$current_page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; // get current page number
$args = array(
'posts_per_page' => 5, // the value from Settings > Reading by default
'paged'          => $current_page // current page
);
query_posts( $args );

$wp_query->is_archive = true;
$wp_query->is_home = false;

while(have_posts()): the_post();
?>





            <article class="blog-box">
                <header>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-1 blog-date">
                            <span class="blog-day"><?php the_time('jS') ?> </span>
                            <span class="blog-month"><?php the_time('M') ?></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-11">
                            <h2><?php the_title() /* post title */ ?></h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </header>
               <?php the_post_thumbnail('blogImage', array( 'class' => "img-responsive")); ?>
                <?php my_excerpt(short);?>  
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" class="more-btn">more</a>
            </article>
            <!-- // blog box  -->
<?php
endwhile;
if( function_exists('wp_pagenavi') ) wp_pagenavi(); // WP-PageNavi function
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

After your custom query while try use  `wp_reset_postdata();`  like this:

```
     <?php
    $current_page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; // get current page number
    $args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5, // the value from Settings > Reading by default
    'paged'          => $current_page // current page
    );
    query_posts( $args );

    $wp_query->is_archive = true;
    $wp_query->is_home = false;

    while(have_posts()): the_post();
    ?>
                <article class="blog-box">
                    <header>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-1 blog-date">
                                <span class="blog-day"><?php the_time('jS') ?> </span>
                                <span class="blog-month"><?php the_time('M') ?></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-11">
                                <h2><?php the_title() /* post title */ ?></h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </header>
                   <?php the_post_thumbnail('blogImage', array( 'class' => "img-responsive")); ?>
                    <?php my_excerpt(short);?>  
                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" class="more-btn">more</a>
                </article>
                <!-- // blog box  -->
    <?php
    endwhile;
    if( function_exists('wp_pagenavi') ) wp_pagenavi(); 

wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
```

Comment: Its not working when i select static page in Settings -> Reading. I made homepage template put query code. Created Homepage and choosed homepage template.  If i choose however Your Latest Posts option its working but last few pages are page 404 :)